# How can I write a simple unit test case in c# for Microsoft Bot framework V4 as it uses .netcore now

Tags: botframework, vs-unit-testing-framework

I have to write Unit test case for BotFramework V4 simple echo method.But I am unable to find a way to mock bot. Actually I don't know where to start with. I have read all documents that I can found on google related to same, but none explains in code level. A concrete example will be great help.

```
  [TestMethod]
    public async Task CreatingAGoodContact()
    {
        var convoState = new ConversationState(new MemoryStorage());

        var adapter = new TestAdapter()
            .Use(new AutoSaveStateMiddleware(convoState));

        var dialogState = convoState.CreateProperty<DialogState> 
                  ("dialogState");

        var dialogs = new DialogSet(dialogState);
        dialogs.Add(CreateWaterfall());

        await new TestFlow(adapter, async (turnContext, 
               cancellationToken) =>
        {
            var dc = await dialogs.CreateContextAsync(turnContext, 
                cancellationToken);

            // await dc.ContinueDialogAsync(cancellationToken);
            if (!turnContext.Responded)
            {
                await dc.BeginDialogAsync("test-waterfall", null, 
                cancellationToken);
            }

        })
        .Send("Say something to start test")
        .AssertReply("What is their first name?")
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to call .StartTestAsync() in order to kick off the execution of the test